# Jitsi On iOS 9 call get disconnected after some seconds of conectiveity

Tags: ios, objective-c, voip, jitsi

### Description

In my system I initiate call procedure form web and send a connect information to client using XMPP message. Once client receive message it joins the room that web created and call get stablished, all this work fine with my iphone 7 and iPad Mini iPod 5th gen  first gen.

But after few second for connectivity on my iPad Mini (iOS 9.1.3) or iPod (IOS 9.1.1) call automatically disconnects.

### Current behavior

Call automatically disconnect after few seconds of activity. Check following log for more details

```
2019-03-07 12:01:43.695 GoSession[255:124762] GSChatManager: xmppStream:didReceiveMessage: message = <message xmlns="jabber:client" from="5c480cfbcdf3060cb68d67c6@xmpp.my.domain.path/7v37be3o1f" to="5c480d7ecdf3060cb68d67cc@xmpp.my.domain.path" type="chat"><body>[{"messageText":"ROOM_NAME","messageType":"call","senderID":"5c480cfbcdf3060cb68d67c6","receiverID":"5c480d7ecdf3060cb68d67cc"}]</body></message>
2019-03-07 12:01:43.696 GoSession[255:124762] Recieved Call Action Notifiation: NSConcreteNotification 0x17f41740 {name = kNotificationCallUpdates; object = <Message: 0x17dc20c0>}
2019-03-07 12:01:46.586 GoSession[255:124762] -[JitsiCallViewViewController conferenceWillJoin:] 
Data:{
    url = "https://video.my.domain.path/ROOM_NAME?jwt=SECRET_KEY#config.startWithVideoMuted=1&config.startWithAudioMuted=0";
}
2019-03-07 12:02:06.239 GoSession[255:124762] -[JitsiCallViewViewController conferenceJoined:] 
Data:{
    url = "https://video.my.domain.path/ROOM_NAME?jwt=SECRET_KEY#config.startWithVideoMuted=1&config.startWithAudioMuted=0";
    user = "{\"_jid\":\"ROOM_NAME@conference.video.my.domain.path/7c010afb\",\"_id\":\"7c010afb\",\"isSelf\":false,\"myID\":\"6bb2321b\"}";
}
2019-03-07 12:02:06.476 GoSession[255:124762] -[JitsiCallViewViewController conferenceJoined:] 
Data:{
    url = "https://video.my.domain.path/ROOM_NAME?jwt=SECRET_KEY#config.startWithVideoMuted=1&config.startWithAudioMuted=0";
}

2019-03-07 12:02:09.145 GoSession[255:124982] [VideoTrackAdapter] Adapter created for track mixedlabelvideo0
2019-03-07 12:02:09.842 GoSession[255:127535] candidate:2131708102 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.0.100 58595 typ host generation 0 <- candidate
2019-03-07 12:02:09.846 GoSession[255:127535] addICECandidateresult: RTCIceCandidate:

0
candidate:2131708102 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.0.100 58595 typ host generation 0
(null)
2019-03-07 12:02:09.849 GoSession[255:127535] candidate:2131708102 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.0.100 64917 typ host generation 0 <- candidate
2019-03-07 12:02:09.865 GoSession[255:127535] addICECandidateresult: RTCIceCandidate:

0
candidate:2131708102 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.0.100 64917 typ host generation 0
(null)
2019-03-07 12:02:09.866 GoSession[255:127535] candidate:831304758 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.0.100 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 <- candidate
2019-03-07 12:02:09.873 GoSession[255:127535] addICECandidateresult: RTCIceCandidate:

0
candidate:831304758 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.0.100 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0
(null)
2019-03-07 12:02:09.873 GoSession[255:127535] candidate:831304758 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.0.100 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 <- candidate
2019-03-07 12:02:09.876 GoSession[255:127535] addICECandidateresult: RTCIceCandidate:

0
candidate:831304758 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.0.100 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0
(null)
2019-03-07 12:02:09.877 GoSession[255:127535] candidate:4266086002 1 udp 1686052607 103.121.115.140 58595 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.100 rport 58595 generation 0 <- candidate
2019-03-07 12:02:09.882 GoSession[255:127535] addICECandidateresult: RTCIceCandidate:

0
candidate:4266086002 1 udp 1686052607 103.121.115.140 58595 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.100 rport 58595 generation 0
(null)
2019-03-07 12:02:09.884 GoSession[255:127535] candidate:4266086002 1 udp 1686052607 103.121.115.140 64917 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.100 rport 64917 generation 0 <- candidate
2019-03-07 12:02:09.886 GoSession[255:127535] addICECandidateresult: RTCIceCandidate:

0
candidate:4266086002 1 udp 1686052607 103.121.115.140 64917 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.100 rport 64917 generation 0
(null)
2019-03-07 12:02:12.146 GoSession[255:124762] [VideoTrackAdapter] Mute event for 8 7560A823-DAD3-4760-9369-F7726AB351DC mixedlabelvideo0
2019-03-07 12:02:12.474 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] '[JitsiConference.js]', '<n>: ', 'Failed to accept incoming Jingle session', { code: '',
  reason: 'item-not-found',
  msg: 'No participant found for: ROOM_NAME@conference.video.my.domain.path/6bb2321b',
  session: 'JingleSessionPC[p2p=false,initiator=false,sid=du2th86f1h07d]' }
2019-03-07 12:02:13.472 GoSession[255:124982] [VideoTrackAdapter] Adapter created for track ae4ac347-45f9-4ceb-a89e-9ac66f1bd10b-1
2019-03-07 12:02:16.508 GoSession[255:124762] [VideoTrackAdapter] Mute event for 9 210366F3-B228-4739-B813-A05096F0F92A ae4ac347-45f9-4ceb-a89e-9ac66f1bd10b-1
2019-03-07 12:02:50:685 GoSession[255:124762] GSChatManager: xmppStream:didReceiveIQ: iq = <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="get" id="723-4451" from="xmpp.my.domain.path" to="5c480d7ecdf3060cb68d67cc@xmpp.my.domain.path/ag9bbenlq0"><ping xmlns="urn:xmpp:ping"></ping></iq>
2019-03-07 12:02:50:688 GoSession[255:124762] GSChatManager: xmppStream:didSendIQ:, IQ = <iq type="error" to="xmpp.my.domain.path" id="723-4451"><ping xmlns="urn:xmpp:ping"></ping><error type="cancel" code="501"><feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"></feature-not-implemented></error></iq>





REJECTION LOG
2019-03-07 12:03:25.492 GoSession[255:124762] -[JitsiCallViewViewController conferenceFailed:] 
Data:{
    error = "conference.setup_failed";
    url = "https://video.my.domain.path/ROOM_NAME?jwt=SECRET_KEY#config.startWithVideoMuted=1&config.startWithAudioMuted=0";
    user = self;
}
2019-03-07 12:03:25.665 GoSession[255:127887] [VideoTrackAdapter] Adapter removed for track mixedlabelvideo0
2019-03-07 12:03:25.743 GoSession[255:127887] [VideoTrackAdapter] Adapter removed for track ae4ac347-45f9-4ceb-a89e-9ac66f1bd10b-1
2019-03-07 12:03:26.003 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] '[__filename]', '<l>: ', '_REMOVE_AUDIO_ELEMENT: no sound for id: PARTICIPANT_JOINED_SOUND'
2019-03-07 12:03:26.030 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] '[__filename]', '<l>: ', '_REMOVE_AUDIO_ELEMENT: no sound for id: PARTICIPANT_LEFT_SOUND'
2019-03-07 12:03:26.054 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] '[__filename]', '<l>: ', '_REMOVE_AUDIO_ELEMENT: no sound for id: RECORDING_OFF_SOUND'
2019-03-07 12:03:26.086 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] '[__filename]', '<l>: ', '_REMOVE_AUDIO_ELEMENT: no sound for id: RECORDING_ON_SOUND'
2019-03-07 12:03:26.117 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] '[__filename]', '<l>: ', '_REMOVE_AUDIO_ELEMENT: no sound for id: OUTGOING_CALL_EXPIRED_SOUND_ID'
2019-03-07 12:03:26.142 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] '[__filename]', '<l>: ', '_REMOVE_AUDIO_ELEMENT: no sound for id: OUTGOING_CALL_REJECTED_SOUND_ID'
2019-03-07 12:03:26.189 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] '[__filename]', '<l>: ', '_REMOVE_AUDIO_ELEMENT: no sound for id: OUTGOING_CALL_RINGING_SOUND_ID'
2019-03-07 12:03:26.215 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] '[__filename]', '<l>: ', '_REMOVE_AUDIO_ELEMENT: no sound for id: OUTGOING_CALL_START_SOUND_ID'
2019-03-07 12:03:27.314 GoSession[255:124981] 12:03:27.314 ERROR:    [worker_thread 0x0x17ed8b80] AVAudioSession.mm:692: -[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.
2019-03-07 12:03:32.243 GoSession[255:124762] GSChatManager: xmppStream:didReceiveMessage: message = <message xmlns="jabber:client" from="5c480cfbcdf3060cb68d67c6@xmpp.my.domain.path/7v37be3o1f" to="5c480d7ecdf3060cb68d67cc@xmpp.my.domain.path" type="chat"><body>[{"messageText":"ROOM_NAME","messageType":"cut","senderID":"5c480cfbcdf3060cb68d67c6","receiverID":"5c480d7ecdf3060cb68d67cc"}]</body></message>
2019-03-07 12:03:32.244 GoSession[255:124762] Recieved Call Action Notifiation: NSConcreteNotification 0x17ff76d0 {name = kNotificationCallUpdates; object = <Message: 0x17d20860>}
```

### Expected Behavior

Call should remain active unless either of calling party disconnect those.

### Possible Solution

I think this have something to do with device capabilities, so better resource management will be helpful.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Launch application on an iPad mini first gen, or ipod 5th gen
2. Connect a call
3. Leave it open for about 60-12 sec

This will automatically disconnect the call.

## Environment details

Device: iPOD 5th Gen, iPad Mini
iOS: 9.1.1, 9.1.3
Internet : 40 Mbps Wifi Connection
One calling end is Web.